# fadeIn fadeOut multiple image background

Tags: jquery, parallax, fade

i created parallax with multiple images that fadeIn fadeOut.

```
   var images = [
    "images/BGK.png",
    "images/slide_2.png",
    "images/PhilBlm.jpg"
    ];
    $bg = $("#elem"),
    n = images.length,
    c = 0; 

    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    var tImg = new Image();
    tImg.src = images[i];
    }


    (function loopBg(){
        var bg = $bg.css({backgroundImage : "url("+images[++c%n]+")"})
        bg.fadeOut(4500, function () {
            loopBg()
        }).fadeIn(4000); 
    }());
```

so this is my script.. with this i was able to display the image with fadeIn fadeOut method..

what i wanted to do is before the image completely fades out i want to fade in the other image cause with this script before the next image fades in it waits the 1st image to completely fades out..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(function loopBg(){
        var bg = $bg.css({backgroundImage : "url("+images[++c%n]+")"})
        bg.fadeOut(4500, function () {
            loopBg()
        })
        bg.fadeIn(4000); 
    }());
```

Comment: what is the diff of this code to the one i posted?.

Comment: In your code, you are waiting to fadeOut end and then you call fadeIn. In my code, I call fadeOut and immediately call fadeIn.

Comment: but when i tried this code the result is the same.. it waits the fadeOut to completely  disappear then calls fadeiN

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to queue the animation, so the fade in will start .5 seconds after the fade out.

```
(function loopBg(){
    var bg = $bg.css({backgroundImage : "url("+images[++c%n]+")"})
    bg.fadeOut(4500, function () {
        loopBg()
    });
    bg.delay(500).fadeIn(4000); 
}());
```

Comment: what i want is to fade in my next image while the 1st image is fading.

Comment: I understand now, but you'll need more than one element to do that.

Comment: i found some samples but it doesn't work if i change it to a parallax background.